# Errored Maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

My dependencies issues:
[image]

My Maven Errors:
[image]

There are around 114 unresolved dependencies showing.
But I see all those dependencies jars under .m2/repositories

Could this be eclipse or maven version issue ??

Comment: Behind a firewall corporate proxy ?

Comment: @khmarbaise No Proxy

Comment: Does your build work on command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise No You can see in the image 
There are lot of errors, its fails to get the dependencies

Comment: try to run mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install

Comment: If you try to run on command line you can see what really the root cause of the problem is...in Eclipse you might not see what happens...So first get you build working on command line and afterwards go into Eclipse..

Comment: @khmarbaise
I have all dependencies in the /m2 folder I manually checked them out.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project *******: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.***:war:1.0.0-07: Failed to collect dependencies at edu.uw.apl.commons:stix-jaxb:jar:111.2.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for edu.uw.apl.commons:stix-jaxb:jar:111.2.0: Could not transfer artifact edu.uw.apl.commons:stix-parent:pom:111.2.0 from/to json-annotation-repo (http://json-annotation.googlecode.com/svn/repo): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Authorization Required. ->

Comment: What do you mean by `checked them out` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I meant I saw them in .m2 folder, I have all the dependency jars

Comment: Have you checked on command line? That's the ultimate test to check for afterwards in Eclipse...